# MKMapView boundaries?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

Anyone know of an easy way to implement boundaries on an MKMapView. For example, I want to tell the map it can only stay in one area. I want to user to be able to scroll but have them stop when they get to a certain latitude/longitude. I tried using the willChangeRegion: delegate but that screwed me over. Thanks.

Comment: I do not see any methods that look like they would do what you are asking for. It sounds like you might have been on the right path with willChangeRegion:. Could you explain what you mean by screwed over?

Comment: Well all I did was check the location of the edge of the map against my defined boundaries and if they were too high, I turned scrolling off. And then I used the other delegate method DidChangeRegion: to turn scrolling back on, which after sleeping on it was probably a mistake. So then I couldn't scroll anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote a blog post about this, check it out here: http://blog.jamgraham.com/blog/2012/04/29/adding-boundaries-to-mkmapview/

I worked on a project with a requirement to lock the boundaries of MKMapView. As there is no out-of-the-box solution provided by apple we are left subclassing MKMapView.  This is pretty easy and gives you access to the UIScrollView that lives in the map and other fun objects in the MKMapView.

Want to look at the code now?  It's available here: https://github.com/jamgraham/geoFencer

Locking the boundaries of the a MKMapView invokes two general steps.  First is to lock the zoom level to a min and max. Second is to prevent the user from scrolling outside the foundry you create.  Lets walk through these by looking at the delegates we need to override

### 1. Zoom Level

This is pretty straight forward.  The goal is the check the zoom level as the user zooms and again when the user stops zooming.

```
 -(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
 -(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale;
```

### 2. Scrolling boundaries

This is a bit more complex.  As the user scrolls around the map in the UIScrollView we want to make sure they do not go outside the boundaries and if they do we want to stop them.  We can achieve this by repositioning the map to the boundary when we see the user go outside the boundary.  This happens fast enough where the users feels like they've hit a wall rather than the map jerking around.  Here are the delegates we need to watch for:

```
 -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
 -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

### 3. Copy & Paste

Feel free to copy and paste the custom MKMapView below. In the UIViewController that show the map the custom map view needs the boundaries set

### ViewController.m

```
    //Set map boundaries
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [mapViewsetZoomMax:0.015551];
    [mapViewsetZoomMin: 0.346360];
    mapView.top = 37.773498;
    mapView.bottom = 37.745130;
    mapView.left = -122.430365;
    mapView.right = -122.401623;
```

### GeoMapView.h

```
@interface GeoMapView : MKMapView
{
    MKCoordinateRegion cordRegion;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D oldcenter;
    double left;
    double right;
    double top;
    double bottom;
    double zoomMax;
    double zoomMin;
}

-(void)checkZoom;
-(void)checkScroll;

@property (nonatomic) double left;
@property (nonatomic) double right;
@property (nonatomic) double top;
@property (nonatomic) double bottom;
@property (nonatomic) double zoomMax;
@property (nonatomic) double zoomMin;

@end
```

### GeoMapView.m

```
#import "GeoMapView.h"

@implementation GeoMapView
@synthesize  left, right, top, bottom,zoomMax,zoomMin;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [superinitWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

    }
    returnself;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [selfcheckZoom];    
}


-(void)checkZoom{
    UIScrollView * scroll = [[[[selfsubviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

    if (scroll.zoomScale < zoomMax) {
        NSLog(@"Reached Max Zoom");
        [scroll setZoomScale:zoomMaxanimated:NO];
    }

    if (scroll.zoomScale >= zoomMin) {
        NSLog(@"Reached Min Zoom");
        [scroll setZoomScale:zoomMinanimated:NO];

    }
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{
    UIScrollView * scroll = [[[[selfsubviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

    if (scroll.zoomScale > zoomMin) {
        [scroll setZoomScale:zoomMinanimated:NO];
    }   
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    [selfcheckScroll];

}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [selfcheckScroll];
}

-(void)checkScroll{
    @try{
        cordRegion = self.region;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D center = self.region.center;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D northWestCorner, southEastCorner;
        northWestCorner.latitude  = center.latitude  + (self.region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
        northWestCorner.longitude = center.longitude - (self.region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
        southEastCorner.latitude  = center.latitude  - (self.region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
        southEastCorner.longitude = center.longitude + (self.region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);

        CLLocationCoordinate2D newcenter;
        newcenter.latitude = self.region.center.latitude;
        newcenter.longitude = self.region.center.longitude;

        //LEFT
        CLLocationDegrees farLeft = left;
        CLLocationDegrees snapToLeft = farLeft + (self.region.span.longitudeDelta  / 2.0);
        if (northWestCorner.longitude < farLeft)
        {
            newcenter.longitude = snapToLeft;
            cordRegion = self.region;
        }

        //RIGHT
        CLLocationDegrees r = (self.region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
        CLLocationDegrees farRight = right;
        CLLocationDegrees snapToRight = farRight - r;
        if (southEastCorner.longitude > farRight)
        {
            newcenter.longitude = snapToRight;
        }

        //TOP
        CLLocationDegrees farTop = top;
        CLLocationDegrees snapToTop = top - (self.region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
        if (northWestCorner.latitude > farTop)
        {
            newcenter.latitude = snapToTop;
        }

        //BOTTOM
        CLLocationDegrees farBottom = bottom;
        CLLocationDegrees rr = (self.region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
        CLLocationDegrees snapToBottom = bottom + rr;
        if (southEastCorner.latitude < farBottom)
        {            
            newcenter.latitude = snapToBottom;
        }

        [selfsetCenterCoordinate:newcenter  animated:NO];

    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {
    }
    @finally {}
}


@end
```

### Ideas

There's a lot of cool stuff going on in geofencing right now. Some ideas:

- Enter an address and lock  the map to that address
- Geofencing with map overlays
- Physical games that unlock areas of the map as the user actually visits those physical places.

Answer (score 0):

So I am going to go ahead and answer my own question and say no there is no **EASY** way to implement this behavior. Not only do you have to check the boundaries, but you also have to check the direction of the scrolling, and the console keeps telling me: *last touch after scroll but scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate: wasn't called!* I guess I have so more research to do...

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing some research and found out there is no easy way of doing it.

So my solution is to have the map locked in a certain area, and have the scrollView which contains the MKMapView to zoom in and out.